# Sending notification to specific user

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two version from my app one for the customer and one for the client I need to send push notification to the specific client(in client app) when the customer take an specific action (in customer app).

I know that I should use Firebase Cloud Messaging as it's a new replacement to GCM, but I can't figure out how I can do this in both server side and client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you have a lot of options here!**

### let's start with the server side:

you have two options HTTP or XMPP, HTTP is a one way connection XMPP is two way.

for your app you will need **XMPP** for upstream and down stream messages
check there Guides it's really great: [Server guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server)

there is also a Java and Node.JS Admin SDKs but i don't know much about.
but there is a great [Tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) which describes the whole proccess if you go for Node.js

### So what happens is:

when a device sends an upstream message

Firebase will forward it to your server

Your server should handle the message and send it to the other device through Firebase cloud messaging

---

you can implement a server-less app using real time databse but you will not receive message in background, but when the receiver app is running it listen to databse changes and send notification to user
you can also make a server listens to databse changes "instead of receiver" and take actions upon it"send a message to the other device"

---

---

### Edit:

with the new cloud function feature you can now use it to send notifications to users based on database events,

- so you can add your message to database in a class
- and make a cloud function to listen to this class write events
- and whenever a message saved to this class, it sends it to desired
  receiver
- so now you don't need an external server to send notifications to
  devices

check [this](https://github.com/mahmoudShaheen/FirebaseDatabaseNotification/fcm-notifications) cloud function sample, it's an example of sending notifications based on database event.